# Export GDB Schema to XML Workspace Document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, basic-license-level, geodatabase-xml

Using ArcGIS 10.2 Basic, the functions to export and import XML workspace documents (gdb schema) are greyed out. 
I have seen the previous discussions here, but the suggestions didn't help. It shouldn't depend on the ArcGIS version or license level, right?

Answer (score 1):

The [Licensing Information for Import XML Workspace](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/import-xml-workspace-document.htm#L_) says:

> - ArcGIS Desktop Basic: No
> - ArcGIS Desktop Standard: Yes
> - ArcGIS Desktop Advanced: Yes

so it looks like you need Standard or Advanced to unlock that functionality.

Comment: Thanks, PolyGeo. I understand that this applies to the tool. Though, in the chapters for exporting and importing 'manually', the help is silent on version requirements. The procedure is well explained, but no mentioning of any limitations when using ArcGIS Desktop Basic.

Comment: Whenever documentation is mentioned I think it is helpful to provide a link to it, and likewise for any "discussions" (actually Q&As) like you mentioned in your question.  Potential answerers can spend more time answering your question if they do not need to repeat your research first.

Comment: For Exporting: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Copying_a_geodatabase_using_geodatabase_XML_workspaces/003n0000002z000000/

Comment: For Importing: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Importing_a_geodatabase_schema_from_an_XML_workspace_document/003n0000002q000000/

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications but I think it very unlikely that the tool licensing will not also apply to the ArcMap GUI.